# Assign variable from async method

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I work with AWS-Amplify and want to get the owner from Cognito and assign it to the variable owner. When I do `console.log(user.username)` inside `then(` I see the right data. However, when I do `console.log(owner);` I only see null.

```
function App() {
  // Get user
  let owner = null;

  Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
    bypassCache: false // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
  })
    .then(user => {
      owner = user.username;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  console.log(owner);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do any side effects inside the component body and if you need to keep some kind of data that's changing over time [`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) is the place for it.

For side effect use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) which can be configured when to fire the callback function using the dependencies array which in this case is empty and will fire the callback function only on mount

```js
function App() {
  const [owner, setOwner] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
      bypassCache: false,
    })
      .then((user) => {
        setOwner(user.username)
      })
      .catch(console.log)
  }, [])

  return <div>{owner}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  // Get user
  let owner = null;

  return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
    bypassCache: false // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
  })
    .then(user => {
      owner = user.username;
      console.log(owner);
      return owner
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

As Auth is async console.log(owner) is executed before the promise resolves. Move it to then to see the result.

Comment: Yes, that way I can also see it. However, I need to access this variable in my return method: `return (<div className="App">User {owner}`. There I only see null.

Comment: you can return it from then function